# Using T-SQL to get the SSIS Package name, job name and description

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the following information out of SQL Server:

- All SSIS Jobs Agent Names.
- SSIS Package Name.
- [optional but nice to have] SSIS Job agent description.

I'm able to pull all 3 of these pieces of information with no problems using the following tables:

- msdb.dbo.sysjobs gives me the Job name and Job description.
- msdb.dbo.sysssispackages gives me the SSIS Package name.

Unfortunately I'm not able to find a correlation between those 2 tables to gets me all 3 pieces of information together.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You will also need to link to msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps. Check the subsystem and command columns for the info you need to complete this.

Comment: The sysjobsteps does have a column called "Command" and yes the package name is in there.  But the command column would need to be parsed to get the SSIS package name out of there.  I've already tried using some fuzzy logic with "LIKE"  but that would give me erroneous data if the package names are alike.  I'm open to suggestions on how to correctly parse out the SSIS package without using fuzzy logic.

Comment: After an extensive search, the answer really is that you need to parse it out of the sysjobsteps command column. If all of the package names inside of sysjobsteps.command are surrounded by double quotes (which seems likely), try something like `LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysssispackages pk ON sysjobs.command LIKE '"' + pk.name + '"' AND sysjobs.subsystem = 'SSIS'

Answer (score 18):

This appears to be a glaring hole by Microsoft - it would be much nicer if the PackageId were stored in the `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps` table, instead of having to parse the information from the Command column. As the OP correctly pointed out, this can be problematic when package names are the same. At any rate, I have been working on a query to provide the following:

1. Job Name
2. Step Name
3. Package Folder Path

-- Get the folder path of the package that a job points to. This brings it all together.

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT 
        J.job_id
        ,JobName = J.name
        ,JS.step_id, JS.step_name, JS.command
        ,StartIndex = 
            CASE 
                WHEN JS.command LIKE '/DTS%' OR JS.command LIKE '/SQL%' OR JS.command LIKE '/ISSERVER%' THEN CHARINDEX('\',JS.command, CHARINDEX('\',JS.command) + 1) --'
                WHEN JS.command LIKE '/SERVER%' THEN CHARINDEX('"', JS.Command, CHARINDEX(' ',command, CHARINDEX(' ',command) + 1) + 1) + 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        ,EndIndex = 
            CASE 
                WHEN JS.command LIKE '/DTS%' OR JS.command LIKE '/SQL%'  OR JS.command LIKE '/ISSERVER%' 
                    THEN  CHARINDEX('"',JS.command, CHARINDEX('\',JS.command, CHARINDEX('\',JS.command) + 1)) --'
                        - CHARINDEX('\',JS.command, CHARINDEX('\',JS.command) + 1) - 1 --'
                WHEN JS.command LIKE '/SERVER%' 
                    THEN  CHARINDEX('"',command, CHARINDEX('"', JS.Command, CHARINDEX(' ',command, CHARINDEX(' ',command) + 1) + 1) + 1)
                        - CHARINDEX('"', JS.Command, CHARINDEX(' ',command, CHARINDEX(' ',command) + 1) + 1) - 1
                ELSE 0
            END
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps JS
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs J
        ON JS.job_id = J.job_id
    WHERE JS.subsystem = 'SSIS'
)    
SELECT 
    C1.job_id
    , C1.JobName
    , C1.step_id
    , C1.step_name
    , PackageFolderPath = 
        CASE 
            WHEN C1.command LIKE '/DTS%' OR C1.command LIKE '/ISSERVER%' THEN SUBSTRING(C1.command, C1.StartIndex, C1.EndIndex)
            WHEN C1.command LIKE '/SQL%' THEN '\MSDB' + SUBSTRING(C1.command, C1.StartIndex, C1.EndIndex)
            WHEN C1.command LIKE '/SERVER%' THEN '\MSDB\' + SUBSTRING(C1.command, C1.StartIndex, C1.EndIndex)
            ELSE NULL
        END
    , C1.command
FROM CTE1 C1
ORDER BY C1.job_id, C1.step_id
```

Comment: This worked for me except the PackageFolderPath. I use File System when deploying.

Comment: This code does not parse the package name out of the step command.

Answer (score 6):

try this,

```
select 
    --Job Information
     a.job_id
    ,a.name
    ,a.description
    --SSIS package Information
    ,b.name
    ,b.id
    ,b.description
    --Job steps Information
    ,js.step_id
    ,js.step_name
    ,js.subsystem
    ,js.command

 from  msdb.dbo.sysjobs  a 
Left Join msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js on js.job_id=a.job_id 
left join msdb.dbo.sysssispackages b
on a.name=b.name
```

Comment: Its an interesting idea, but an SSIS package doesn't necessarily have the same name as the job executing the package... especially when you have a job that executes two or more packages.

Comment: The b.name column is showing NULL even though I'm seeing jobs on a server running SSIS and having a package running in it.

Comment: possibly because of job name and package name are different.Generally I use same name for package and job so it's easy to keep track of things. the other possible solution is to go with `**Laughing Vergil**` (comment above) and `**Laughing Vergil**` thanks for pointing that... I know that but I wasn't aware because I use same naming convention.

Answer (score 5):

i also searched for an solution, this is working for me:

```
declare @MyJobTable table 
(
JobName nvarchar(255)
,StepName nvarchar(255)
,StepID int
,SSIDName nvarchar(255)
,StepCommand nvarchar(1024)
)

declare @MyCursor as cursor
declare @MyName as nvarchar(255)

set @MyCursor = CURSOR for select name from msdb.dbo.sysssispackages

open @mycursor
fetch next from @MyCursor into @MyName

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin 

insert into @MyJobTable
(JobName,StepName,StepID,SSIDName,StepCommand)
(select
jobs.name as JobName
,steps.step_name as StepName
,steps.step_id as StepID
,@MyName as SSIDName
,steps.command as StepCommand
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs as jobs
join msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps as steps
on jobs.job_id = steps.job_id
where steps.subsystem = 'SSIS'
and steps.command like '%'+@MyName+'%')
fetch next from @MyCursor into @MyName

end

select * from @MyJobTable
order by JobName,StepID
```

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: This does not return anything in my database.