# Is there a way to link a SQL Agent Job step that calls a package back to its package record in SSISDB?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I am building some reports around our SQL Agent jobs and a lot of them call packages from the Integration Services catalog. When a step of a job calls a package, I am wanting to know whether the package is somehow referenced in the job step by its SSISDB package_id or by its package_guid?

If not, is there any other known way I can derive the package_id or package_guid?

I have looked extensively at Microsoft's documentation but cannot find what I am looking for.

Of course, I am looking at the sysjobstep table. And while I can see the name of the package that is being called in the command column, it does not reference the package by any kind of ID as far as I can tell. (And it includes a bunch of other things like my SSIS project parameter values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse a `command` column from `sysjobsteps` table.
Following post has a nice query how to do it:
[Using T-SQL to get the SSIS Package name, job name and description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489743/using-t-sql-to-get-the-ssis-package-name-job-name-and-description)

Answer (score 1):

Believe by name is all we have to go on and not what you wanted to hear. I keep this around for when I'm hunting for a package reference.

```
select 
    '------>' 'Job Information'
    ,a.job_id
    ,a.name
    ,a.description
    ,'------>' 'SSIS package Information' 
    ,b.name
    ,b.id
    ,b.description
    ,'------>' 'Job steps Information' 
    ,js.step_id
    ,js.step_name
    ,js.subsystem
    ,js.command
from  msdb.dbo.sysjobs  a 
left Join msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js on js.job_id=a.job_id 
left join msdb.dbo.sysssispackages b on js.command like '%'+b.name + '%'
```